# Evaluating $\log_3(1+2(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1))$ in the most efficient way

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have come across a tricky question while studying logarithms.

$$\log_3(1+2(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1))$$

While plugging it into a calculator brings a seemingly simple answer, I cannot find a way to start this without a calculator.

Comment: Hint : $2=3-1.$

Comment: $$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+x^{2^k})=\sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1} x^j=\frac{x^{2^n}-1}{x-1}.$$ So: $$1+(x-1)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+x^{2^k})=x^{2^n}$$ In your case, $x=3, n=6.$

Comment: You have typed out an expression, but you haven't asked a question. What is it that you want to do with that expression?

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I hadn't realized that my question was not in the text. I was wondering how to begin to simplify this expression. I have figured out how to simplify it now.

Comment: Good! let me encourage you to write up your solution & post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I have submitted an answer to my question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $\log_3(1+2(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1))$ as $\log_3(1+(3-1)(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1))$. You can use the Difference of Squares formula to find $\log_3(1+(3^2-1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1))$. If you use the Difference of Squares formula 5 times, you get $\log_3(1+(3^{64}-1))$. Finally, by removing the parenthesis, you get $\log_3(3^{64}+1-1)$, which simplifies to $\log_3(3^{64})$. Now, with the logarithm power rule, this becomes $64\log_3(3)$, which is equal to $64$.

Comment: I am not following how you performed the "simplification"...I'd rather you considered  
"Thomas Andrews" approach in Comments above. It is neat.

Comment: Oh, I repeatedly used the Difference of Squares formula. It states that x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y). Since you have (3-1)(3+1), it becomes (3^2-1). Then, (3^2-1)(3^2+1) gives you (3^4-1). From there, (3^4-1)(3^4+1) gives you (3^8-1). You can repeat this until you have (3^32-1)(3^32+1), which gives you (3^64-1). Finally, you can take it out of the parenthesis, and since you have 1 + (3^64-1), you get 3^64.

Comment: I can edit my answer to include the above process.

Comment: No. still something is not clear here. Could you apply this simplification you described to a simple case: $(3^{2}+1)(4^{2}+1)$?

Comment: No you could not because you do not have a case where you can use the Difference of Squares formula. The process that I used was not a general process, but rather a specific process that I could use because I had a difference of squares. This Difference of Squares formula states that x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y). In this case, since I had (3-1)(3+1), so this can become (3^2-1^2), which is equal to (3^2-1). Likewise, I also have (3^2+1), so I can apply this again. I would get ((3^2)^2-1^2), which is equal to (3^4-1). Similarly, I would continue using the formula.

Comment: Thank you for trying to explain. I need to inspect this process of decomposition.